# What is sealing the edges of this footpath?

Tags: sealing

I want to fill the cracks in between the foundation and stone pathway adjacent to it.

In this first picture, you can see the void between the foundation and the stones.

[image: Missing Seal]

But if you were to turn 180°, you'd see a less weathered (although hardly doing a complete job) seal. (grout?)

[image: Less-Missing Seal]

I wonder - can anyone identify the sealing material in picture? If so, what is it, can I buy and apply more of it very easily? Bonus: will it have any material effect on insects that may be going under and around the door to get inside the house?

Comment: Is it hard like cement or pliable?

Comment: Pliable. Brittle, too, after being dried out by the sun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like polymeric sand to me.  [Here's a description of how it's used to fill the joints.](https://www.thespruce.com/what-is-polymeric-sand-2132510)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like (just dirt actually) **asphalt** concrete expansion joint material. But it doesn't really matter what it is if it didn't come out a caulking gun. To insert an expansion joint you'd probably have to pull the first row of bricks up.

Google *vulkem* caulk if you want a way to easily do it and have something that will remain flexible for upwards of 20 years. Read the warning labels. This stuff works really well, which means it's *very* bad for you.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the paving stones will move over time, especially if you live somewhere with freezing winters. If you fill the gaps with anything rigid or semi-rigid, it'll crack. What I would do is pour some sand over the top, and use a broom to sweep it into the gaps.